# Bash While loop is not looping

Tags: bash

Im doing a backup script for Mikrotik devices using bash. I want to use a while loop that will read from a file.

The Contents of the file to read from will be like:

```
1.1.1.1 router1
2.2.2.2 router2
```

Here is my sample script:

```
while read -r ip name
do

sshpass -p "pass" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no export\@$ip "/export;/quit" 2> errors.log >> $name.export

done < iplistandnamefile
```

The problem is that the script will work for only the 1st IP address on the iplistandnamefile file but will not loop to the 2nd IP.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: The `while` loop works fine, am not sure of the syntax of the `sshpass` command, the proper syntax is `sshpass -p "pass" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@host command_to_run`.  What are you trying to achieve with `export`?

Comment: the sshpass is working since ive generated an export file for the 1st IP in the list.

yah export is the command i want to run. I want to use the while loop so I can use multiple variable when reading the file. Currently I have a working for loop script that reads from a file containing only IP addresses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ssh is eating the rest of the file as it defaults to reading stdin

add -n to the ssh command.

```
sshpass -p "pass" ssh -no StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@host command_to_run
```

Comment: It works.. but i cant fully grasp the function of the -n flag.

Comment: -n redirects /dev/null to stdin whereas without it, the whole contents of your file become stdin to ssh